# @ViewBag Trae los datos pero no los muestra

Tags: ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo una vista la cual muestra mediante `ViewBag` determinados datos, cuando hago `Debug` los `ViewBag` traen los datos correspondientes del controlador, pero por alguna razón en la vista no se muestran.

Debug:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Jquery `Ajax`

```js
let RangoValorCredito = $('#RangoValorCredito').html($('#RangoValorCredito').val());
let CreditoValor = $('#Valor');
let CreditoPlazo = $('#Plazo');
RangoValorCredito.change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CalcularSimulador',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { Valor: CreditoValor.val(), Plazo: CreditoPlazo.val() },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Satisfactoria');
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                console.log('Insatisfactoria', ex);
                
            }
        });

        CreditoValor.val($(this).val()).toLocaleString('es-CO');
        if ($(this).val() > medValor) {
            textoMedValor.css('display', 'block');
            textoMedValor.text('Si es tú primera vez puedes pedir hasta' + ' ' + '$' + medValor);
        }
        else {
            textoMedValor.css('display', 'none');
        }
      

    });
```

Controladores

```
private Entity.Credito.Common.ResponseCreditoType parametro;
    private Entity.Credito.Common.ResponseCreditoType liquidar;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ParametrosInteresesModel model = new ParametrosInteresesModel();
        Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req = llenarReq(250000,30);
        llenarViewBag(req);
        if (parametro.respuesta.Codigo == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.PlazoMaximo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMaximo;
            ViewBag.PlazoMinimo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMinimo;
            ViewBag.ValorMaximo = parametro.parametro.ValorMaximo;
            ViewBag.ValorMinimo = parametro.parametro.ValorMinimo;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ErrorData", "Error");
        }

        model.req = req;
        //MessageBox.Show(resultado.respuesta.Codigo.ToString() + " - " + resultado.respuesta.Mensaje);
        return View(model);
    }



    private void llenarViewBag(Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req)
    {
        parametro = new Entity.Credito.Common.ResponseCreditoType();
        liquidar = new Entity.Credito.Common.ResponseCreditoType();
        ICreditoProcesoBehavior _loginBL = FabricaCredito.CrearLogicaCreditoProceso();
        parametro = _loginBL.ConsultarParametro(req);
        liquidar = _loginBL.LiquidarCredito(req);

    }
    private Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType llenarReq(int Valor , int Plazo)
    {
        Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req = new Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType();
        req.autenticacion = new Entity.Credito.Common.AutenticaWSType();
        req.autenticacion.IdCliente = 18;
        req.autenticacion.Identificacion = 8301246257;
        req.autenticacion.IdEstrategia = 1;
        req.autenticacion.Token = "Gi2ESrGr53pwTWpcRzWP+o6Fhr+FHNjcjuoNPcHVI4IxMjM0NTY3OA==";
        req.autenticacion.CodigoCliente = 12345678;
        req.solicitud = new Entity.Credito.Common.SolicitudType();

        req.solicitud.Valor = Valor;// 250000;
        req.solicitud.Plazo = Plazo;//30;

        return req;
    }
    public ActionResult CalcularSimulador(int Valor, int Plazo)
    {
        ParametrosInteresesModel model = new ParametrosInteresesModel();
        Entity.Credito.Common.RequestCreditoType req = llenarReq(Valor, Plazo);
        llenarViewBag(req);
        if (parametro.respuesta.Codigo == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.PlazoMaximo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMaximo;
            ViewBag.PlazoMinimo = parametro.parametro.PlazoMinimo;
            ViewBag.ValorMaximo = parametro.parametro.ValorMaximo;
            ViewBag.ValorMinimo = parametro.parametro.ValorMinimo;
            ViewBag.ValorSolicitado = liquidar.solicitud.Valor.ToString();
            ViewBag.ValorSeguro = liquidar.solicitud.ValorSeguro;
            ViewBag.ValorInteres = liquidar.solicitud.ValorInteres;
            ViewBag.ValorEstudio = liquidar.solicitud.CostoEstudio;
            ViewBag.ValorPlataforma = liquidar.solicitud.CostoPlataforma;
            ViewBag.ValorIva = liquidar.solicitud.IVA;
            ViewBag.ValorTotal = liquidar.solicitud.Total;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ErrorData", "Error");
        }
        model.req = req;
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Vista Index dónde se muestran los datos:

```html
@model Zolev.UI.Credito.Models.ParametrosInteresesModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserRegister", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmCreate", @class = "frmClass" }))
{
    <!--=============================
     Sección del simulador de credito
     ==============================-->
    <div class="contenedorSecundario">
        <div class="tituloPrestamo" style="border: solid 1px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);">
            <h3 class="colorBlanco">¡CALCULA TU PRÉSTAMO!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedorCalendario" id="contenedorCalendario">
            <h4 id="valorMedio">¿Que monto necesitas?</h4>
            <div class="alertaCantidad" id="textoMedValor">
            </div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "inputText" } })
            <span class="underline"></span>
            <div class="rangoActivo">
                <input type="range" id="RangoValorCredito" maxlength="7" step="10000" class="slider" />
            </div>
            <div class="MaxMin1">
                @Html.Label((int)ViewBag.ValorMinimo + "", new { @id = "ValorMinimo" })
                @Html.Label((int)ViewBag.ValorMaximo + "", new { @id = "ValorMaximo" })
            </div>
            <!---Calendario -->
            <div id="datepicker" class="calendarioPrinipal"></div>
            <!---Fin del Calendario -->
            <div class="rangoActivo1">
                <input type="range" id="RangoPlazoCredito" maxlength="2" step="1" class="slider" />
            </div>
            <div class="MaxMin1">
                @Html.Label((int)ViewBag.PlazoMinimo + " " + "Dias", new { @id = "PlazoMinimo" })
                @Html.Label((int)ViewBag.PlazoMaximo + " " + "Dias", new { @id = "PlazoMaximo" })
            </div>
            <div class="inputsMenu">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plazo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "inputText" } })
            </div>
            <span class="underline"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--=============================
     Fin sección del simulador de credito
     ==============================-->
    <!--==========================================
     Sección de barra de calculos correspondientes
     ==========================================-->
    <div class="contenedorSecundario2">
        <div class="contenedorBarra">
            <div class="barraIntereses">
                <div class="titulosIntereses">
                    <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorCredito1">Valor Solicitado</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="MostrarValorCredito">@ViewBag.ValorSolicitado</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorInteres1">Interés</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="valorInteres">@ViewBag.ValorInteres</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorSeguro1">Seguro</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="valorSeguro">@ViewBag.ValorSeguro</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorEstudio1">Estudio</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="valorEstudio">@ViewBag.ValorEstudio</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenidoIntereses separador">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorPlataforma1">Plataforma</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="valorPlataforma">@ViewBag.ValorPlataforma</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contenidoIntereses">
                        <p class="colorNegro" id="valorIva1">Iva</p>
                        <p class="colorRojo" id="valorIva">@ViewBag.ValorIva</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--==========================================
        Sección gran total
        ==========================================-->

        <div class="granTotal">
            <div class="tituloTotal">
                <p>Total a pagar:</p>
                <p id="valorTotal" class="valorTotal">@ViewBag.ValorTotal</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="botonPrinipal">
                <button class="botonGrande" type="submit" id="solicitarPrestamo">!Solicitar Prestamo¡</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--==========================================
        Fin sección gran total
        ==========================================-->

    </div>
    <!--==============================================
     Fin sección de barra de calculos correspondientes
     ==============================================-->
    <div class="imagenMedia">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/7-06.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="tituloSolicitar">
        <h1>Requisitos para solicitar mi préstamo</h1>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
     Sección imagenes requisitos
    ============================================-->
    <div class="imagenesRequisito">
        <div class="primeraImagen">
            <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List1.png" />
            <p>Estar residiendo en Colombia</p>
        </div>
        <div class="segundaImagen">
            <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List2.png" />
            <p>Ser mayor de 18 años</p>
        </div>
        <div class="terceraImagen">
            <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List3.png" />
            <p>Poseer una cta de ahorros o corriente</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cuartaImagen">
            <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List4.png" />
            <p>Direccion de correo electrónico propio</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quintaImagen">
            <img src="~/Content/imagenes/List5.png" />
            <p>Número celular propio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
     Fin sección imagenes requisitos
    ============================================-->
    <div class="imagenModos">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/fondoModos.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="separadorGrande">
        <img src="~/Content/imagenes/separadorGrande.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="comoFuncionamos">
        <h2>Así es como funcionamos</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="leerMas">
        <button class="botonLeer">
            Leer más
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
     Sección Imagenes Aliados
     ==========================================-->
    <div class="nuestrosAliados">
        <h2>Nuestros aliados</h2>
    </div>
    <!--==========================================
     Fin sección Imagenes Aliados
    ==========================================-->
    <div class="nuestrosAliadosImagenes">
        <div class="slider1">
            <div class="slide-track">
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/primerAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/segundoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/tercerAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/cuartoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/quintoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/sextoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/septimoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/octavoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/novenoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/decimoAliado.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide1">
                    <img src="~/Content/imagenes/onecavoAliado.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: Todo parece correcto. Que tiene la clase CSS `colorRojo`?

Comment: Solo contiene la propiedad color:red

Comment: Prueba con un @(ViewBag.ValorTotal) a ver, o un @Write(ViewBag.ValorTotal)

Comment: con la primera opción `@(ViewBag.ValorTotal)` trae el dato pero no lo muestra en la vista con la opción `@Write(ViewBag.ValorTotal)` genera un error que dice: _No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'object'_